# What would I observe with a light microscope operating at its full magnification if the specimen was smaller in diameter than the used wavelength?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Would I still **see** the specimen **but** completely blurry? or wouldn't I see it **at all**? For example, let's say the wavelength of the light used is 600nm and the diameter of the specimen is 550nm.

Comment: It's called the diffraction limit. So diffraction,, so that sounds reasonable.